# Как работать в OpenServer с локальной версией сайта с HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, openserver

Мой сайт работает через HTTPS. Для отладки я перенес его на локальный сервер OpenServer. Имя домена на локальном сервере не менял. При запущенном локальном сервере браузер естественно выдает ошибку о недействительном SSL сертификате. Как сделать так, чтобы сайт открывался с локального сервере через HTTPS ?

Comment: Сделать сертификат действительным, очевидно. Как сделать — решать вам

Comment: Вот тут все подробно написано про SSL на OpenSever - https://go-job.ru/site-building/hosting/local-hosting/ustanovka-ssl-v-openserver.html